# Owncloud - mutiple HTTP 404 log records

Tags: nginx, owncloud, http-status-code-404

Since I've uninstall Owncloud I have multiple HTTP 404 response from owncloud requests in my NGINX http server log.

It is obviously a heartbeat request but I can't find out from which server it's sent.

```
192.168.1.254 - jeby6372 [10/Jun/2014:10:07:12 +0200] "GET /owncloud/status.php HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) mirall/1.5.2"
```

How to stop these requests ?

Answer (score 0):

The log suggests that it's coming from a service located at 192.168.1.254. Mirall is the Owncloud Desktop Client. Perhaps a client is still trying to reach the Owncloud service?

Comment: Sure , that what I meant by refering to a "heartbeat program" but I've no such client in my home network ....

Comment: The request has to be coming from somewhere. Perhaps you have a router at 192.168.1.254 and an external client is polling the server through port-forwarding?

Comment: my router is 192.168.1.254, it receives these external requests from somewhere but where is it originated. Actually I just wanted to know if someone already faced this case